# SSL client certificate authentication with Java2se html-unit

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, htmlunit, unit-testing

I am currently using htmlunit to simulate scrapping of a  web page that requires an ssl client certificate to be installed (https connection). This certificate has successfully been installed in my windows OS . On access of the given webpage via web browsers(chrome & IE), a prompt is issued to select a personal certificate that will be used .  I would like to access the windows cert store preferably this personal certificate to authenticate and create a successful connection to my htmlunit client.

I have managed to research on the SunMSCAPI with Windows-MY to read the store as shown in below code.

```
        Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunMSCAPI");
        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", provider);
        store.load(null, null);

        Enumeration<?> aliases = store.aliases();
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = aliases.nextElement().toString();
            if (alias.equals("mypersonalcert")) {

                Certificate[] signerKey = (Certificate[]) store
                        .getCertificateChain(alias);
                Object entry = store.getKey(alias, null);
                System.out
                        .println("cert aquired! got it");

            }
        }
```

How do I successfully integrate this to my htmlunit webconnection and web client instance for connection? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use
 WebClientOptions.setSSLClientCertificate(URL certificateUrl,String certificatePassword, String certificateType)

to point HTMLUnit to the client certificate of your choice.